# ¿Cómo pasar una doble variable por php?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas estoy ideando mi proyecto de clase en PHP con Mysqli, y tengo lo siguiente:

Básicamente busco un vuelo mediante una ciudad de origen y otra de destino, al encontrar un vuelo se me muestra de la siguiente manera:
[image: foto de pantalla]

Y el checkbox del precio seleccionado lo recibo en la siguiente página, es decir, si marqué el primero se me pasa 7.000, el segundo me pasa 25.000, el tercero 50.000 y el último 100.000 (como se ve en la foto)

Hasta ahí voy bien, sin embargo si se dan cuenta cada precio pertenece a una clase, por lo tanto al elegir los asientos debo saber qué clase elegí antes... la primera la definí como turista, la segunda ejecutiva y así.

Mi duda es, de qué forma puedo pasar el parámetro de clase, aunque sea predefinido, junto con el precio, a la siguiente página? Como expliqué solo logro pasar el precio mediante el value del checkbox.

De esta manera obtengo el precio:

```
    $result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tarifas WHERE cod_tarifa='1' AND cod_origen='$origgen' AND cod_salida='$destino'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) 

    { 
    ?>

<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="es" value="<?php echo $row['valor']; ?>" onclick="check2(this)" ><?php echo $row['valor']; ?> <b>PESOS</b>
                                                <?php
    }
```

Entonces me gustaría saber que si marqué el primero (además del precio que ya lo pasa) una variable me pase un 1, si marqué el segundo me pase un 2 y así. 
Agradezco su apoyo para guiarme

> Edición: Función check2

```
function check2(box) {
if (box.checked) {
document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked=false
document.getElementById("checkbox3").checked=false
document.getElementById("checkbox4").checked=false
}
}
```

Básicamente lo que hace es permitir sólo seleccionar un checkbox.

Comment: Los datos los envías por medio de ajax o por método convencional ?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Hola, los envío de forma convencional, mediante GET

Comment: podrías tener un <input type="hidden"> el cual con javascript le damos un valor dependiendo la casilla que han seleccionado, podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código de la función check2()?

Comment: También podrías ponerle al checkbox un valor que fuese la concatenación del valor y el id. Por ejemplo `<?php echo $row['id'] .'|' . $row['valor']; ?>`. Luego al recibirlo en el paso siguiente haces un explode de lo que recibiste sabiendo que la primera parte es el ID de la clase y la segunda parte es el precio

Comment: De la forma en lo que lo estás haciendo, ¿Existe la forma de que el usuario cambie el precio y se envié con el precio cambiado a la siguiente página? cuidado con eso. quizás lo más correcto es que cada oferta/opción tenga una ID junto a su precio en la base de datos, y en la siguiente página recuperes esa ID con todos los datos, entre ellos el precio.

Comment: Agradezco sus guías, lo he resuelto perfectamente con la guía de @amenadiel. Ty!

Comment: @amenadiel Eso haría que sea bastante inseguro :-/

Comment: Obviamente mandar el precio en un input no es la mejor idea, pero si quiere enviar dos variables en una, como solución genérica, es lo que yo hago. La solución óptima sería encriptar (no hashear) esa concatenación y desencriptarla en el POST siguiente con la llave almacenada en el servidor